# Трехсмысленные фразы??

Tags: значение-слов

День добрый. Встретил в тексте словосочетание 'Трехсмысленные фразы' и на долго задумался, никак не могу придумать хоть какой пример. Помогите.

´Примерно тем же
тоном, как в детстве, когда у меня не выходила
задачка по дифференциальному исчислению
или я никак не мог усвоить параграфы
Галактического Кодекса – с их официально
трехсмысленным толкованием и перекрестными
ссылками"...´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый известный пример текста, который можно расшифровать тремя и более способами - это **Косил косой косой косой**. Предложение можно расшифровать как:

1. Косоглазый человек косил траву кривой косой.
2. Косой заяц косил траву кривой косой.
3. Косоглазый человек, выкурив косяк, косил траву косой.

Вечером постараюсь ещё найти стихотворение с тремя смыслами в зависимости от того как его читать.

---

А вот и сам "Сонет, заключающий в себе три мысли" Алексея Ржевского (1737-1804). Читать нужно всё вместе (1), только первые полустишия (2), только вторые полустишия (3)

```
      Вовеки не пленюсь          красавицей иной;
      Ты ведай, я тобой          всегда прельщаться стану,
      По смерть не пременюсь;    вовек жар будет мой,
      Век буду с мыслью той,     доколе не увяну.

      Не лестна для меня         иная красота;
      Лишь в свете ты одна       мой дух воспламенила.
      Скажу я не маня:           свобода отнята—
      Та часть тебе дана         о ты, что дух пленила!

      Быть ввек противной мне,   измены не брегись,
      В сей ты одна стране       со мною век любись.
      Мне горесть и беда,        я мучуся тоскою,

      Противен мне тот час,      коль нет тебя со мной;
      Как зрю твоих взор глаз,   минутой счастлив той,
      Смущаюся всегда            и весел, коль с тобою.
```

Comment: про косого - это всего лишь разные значения слова "косой"

смысл всей фразы в данном случае не меняется

Comment: Фразу можно интерпретировать тремя разными способами, причём смысл фразы в зависимости от интерпретации меняется существенно. Никто не спорит, это достигнуто за счёт омонимии, но ограничения на омонимы в вопросе не было.

Answer (score 6):

Слова *трехсмысленный* в словарях не зафиксировано. Есть двусмысленный - двоякий, уклончивый... Интересно, в каком тексте и в каком контексте употреблялось слово. Чтобы придумать, надо смысл понимать. Это может быть окказиональное выражение со значением многозначности, "трехсмысленности". Но без контекста трудно.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что "трехсмысленные фразы" - это все лишь игра слов. Есть шутка, что у двух юристов три мнения. Я не читала Галактического Кодекса, но могу предположить, что он мало отличается от любого из известных мне земных кодексов.

Answer (score 3):

"Трёхсмысленный", конечно, употреблено (в исходном примере) иронически, для описания сильной неоднозначности.
"Двусмысленный" -- термин, вполне достаточный для определения слова или оборота с многими значениями, смыслами.

"Дву-" здесь значит не ровно "два", а просто "больше одного". Язык это не арифметика.
Можно говорить "многозначный" (хотя это больше годится на роль лингвистического термина)

Answer (score 1):

Да, перед тем, как отвечать на такой вопрос, надо понять, что значит "официально трехсмысленным толкованием". Возможно, это лишь впечатление свежего человека от юридической казуистики, когда на каждое слово формулировки и их сочетания можно дать объяснение (и ооочень объёмное), почему сказано именно так, и почему с иной формулировкой желаемый **единственный** смысл потеряется.

А у Стругацких ("Жук в муравейнике") приводился пример фразы ("Мы любознательны, но не любопытны"), имеющей **два** смысла, и оба смысла - это именно то, что хотел сказать говорящий (и то, что раса голованов не суёт свой нос, куда не просят, и то, что не желает, чтобы в их дела совали нос из-за досужего любопытства).

Answer (score 1):

Примеров двусмысленности несчесть в законодатенльстве РФ. например ст.60 жилищного кодекса. Г. Крашенинников постаралось.

Comment: "Г. Крашенинников постаралОсь" - это тоже какая-то трехсмысленная фраза...или намёк:)

Answer (score 1):

Значительная часть слов являются многозначными, но обычно текст строится таким образом,что определить конкретное  значение несложно.

Двусмысленность - это когда для данной ситуации подходят два значения (обычно не больше, поэтому термин "трехсмысленный" отсутствует).

Иногда двусмысленность создается сама собой, но часто это делается намеренно. Недаром вторым значением у этого слова является "содержащий неприличный или нескромный намек).